# Adding Role Based Redirection Upon Login to React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, role-base-authorization, role-based-access-control

So I have an app that currently works fine on login, just takes you to the basic app. I created a new page called AdminDashboard.js, and added a new part to the json called "Admin" which is set to 1 for admin users and 0 for everyone else. I don't know where to add a redirection where, if the user logging in is an admin, they will go to the AdminDashboard.js instead of the App.js part.

The JSON looks like

```
{
    "FirstName": "", 
    "LastName": "", 
    "Email": "admin", 
    "ID": 12, 
    "Admin": 1, 
    "Submitted": 0, 
    "Token": "eyJ0e1NiJ9.eNTYzMjA0NTkEyfQ._K5qNdsqJJXCiKq3XmIjFhU"
}
```

And the current summarized code is similar to this for the used pages, not including AdminDashboard.js

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

// Our Components
import Login from './components/Login';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </div>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AuthService from './components/AuthService';
import withAuth from './components/withAuth';
const Auth = new AuthService();

class App extends Component {

  handleLogout(){
    Auth.logout()
    this.props.history.replace('/login');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome {this.props.user.email}</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          <button type="button" className="form-submit" onClick={this.handleLogout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(App);
```

**AuthService.js**

```
export default class AuthService {
    constructor(domain) {
        this.domain = domain || 'http://10.123.456.321'
        this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this)
    }

    login(email, password) {
        // Get a token
        return this.fetch(`${this.domain}/Login/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        }).then(res => {
            this.setToken(res.Token)
            return Promise.resolve(res);
        })
    }

    loggedIn() {
        // Checks if there is a saved token and it's still valid
        const token = this.getToken()
        return !!token && !this.isTokenExpired(token) // handwaiving here
    }

    isTokenExpired(token) {
        try {
            const decoded = decode(token);
            if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    setToken(idToken) {
        // Saves user token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
    }

    getToken() {
        // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    }

    logout() {
        // Clear user token and profile data from localStorage
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    }

    getProfile() {
        return decode(this.getToken());
    }


    fetch(url, options) {
        // performs api calls sending the required authentication headers
        const headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        if (this.loggedIn()) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
        }

        return fetch(url, {
            headers,
            ...options
        })
            .then(this._checkStatus)
            .then(response => response.json())
    }

    _checkStatus(response) {
        // raises an error in case response status is not a success
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return response
        } else {
            var error = new Error(response.statusText)
            error.response = response
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

**withAuth.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthService from './AuthService';

export default function withAuth(AuthComponent) {
    const Auth = new AuthService('http://10.123.456.321');
    return class AuthWrapped extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                user: null
            }
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
                this.props.history.replace('/login')
            }
            else {
                try {
                    const profile = Auth.getProfile()
                    this.setState({
                        user: profile
                    })
                }
                catch(err){
                    Auth.logout()
                    this.props.history.replace('/login')
                }
            }
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.user) {
                return (
                    <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user} />
                )
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import AuthService from './AuthService';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.Auth = new AuthService();
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        if(this.Auth.loggedIn())
            this.props.history.replace('/');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="center">
                <div className="card">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                        <input
                            className="form-item"
                            placeholder="Username goes here..."
                            name="username"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            className="form-item"
                            placeholder="Password goes here..."
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <input
                            className="form-submit"
                            value="SUBMIT"
                            type="submit"
                        />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleFormSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.Auth.login(this.state.username,this.state.password)
            .then(res =>{
               this.props.history.replace('/');
            })
            .catch(err =>{
                alert(err);
            })
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState(
            {
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow the way of React role-based access control and after login success you can check if the user is admin then you have to add route for the component AdminDashboard.js otherwise route to '/'.

you can look for an example I made: https://github.com/NemerSahli/React-Role-Based-Access-Control

Comment: this methods looks good. but i want to pass props to component how can i achieve that